# Is there a way to comment out python code in a django html file?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm curious, i have the following code `{% code_goes_here %}`, how do I comment it out in the html file?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but `<!-- ... -->`?

Answer (score 8):

Django templates has `{# ... #}` as comments. NOTE: These comments are not multi-line.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to comment in templates as other people have mentioned in their answers, so I thought I'll quickly summarize them below:

As brc mentioned above, you could use HTML comments `<!-- -->` 
but the comment *would* show if the user views the source of the page.

For single line comments in templates, use: 
    `{# ... #}`

For multi-line comments in templates, use:

```
{% comment %}
{% code_goes_here %}
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 1):

this this what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#comment

Comment: It is only one sentence, why not copy the relevant passage?

Answer (score 1):

```
{# Your comment goes here,which will not be seen in template #}
```